# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Java heap space MyEclipse JBoss

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, myeclipse

I keep getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` Java heap space in `MyEclipse` JBOSS. I tried increasing the memory allocated to JBoss.
But I am still getting the error. Am I doing something wrong or do I need to add more memory?

I am using MyEclipse for Spring version 10. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You possibly have a memory leak.  Search for Q&A's on finding Java memory leaks.

Comment: Are you using the 32bit or 64bit-version of Java? Memory-errors are common with Java32.

Comment: yes i am using 64bit-version.

Comment: If you are using MyEclipse for Spring 10 - then that's a really old version (nearly 10 years old) and I would recommend moving to a more recent version. Does deployment fail with this error, or do you get this as your application is in use? If the latter, perhaps you have a leak in the app. If you need additional help, do create a post on the MyEclipse forums: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/myeclipse/